# How to save a Worksheet to pdf using excel online scripts

Tags: excel, office365, excel-online

I am trying to save a worksheet as a PDF and then send it to an email.  Right now I have a sheet set up for taking form responses and in the same workbook I have a sheet that displays the answers of the form in an organized and readable manner.  I want to be able to write a script that when a form response is submitted the organized answers are saved as a PDF and sent as an email.  I have tried using power automate but I can't figure out how to set the worksheet as dynamic content.  I can't find any resources on saving as PDF with an excel online script or setting the worksheet as dynamic content that can be used in power automate.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check on here - several q&a about saving worksheets as pdf, some with example code.

Comment: All the Q&A are about VBA. I am hoping to do it in JavaScript with the online version of Excel

Comment: So you could benefit from the approach and develop that. What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Writing the VBA isn't a problem, I need the macro to fire every time a form response is submitted without having the excel workbook open.  As far as I know, you can't trigger a VBA macro with power automate when a form is submitted.